# HTML scraping with R and selectorgadget

Tags: r

I have a script below that works for simple html scraping. Nothing is returned below for this particular site. New to using html with R and selectorgadget but I have other sites that work. I am wondering why this one does not see the element. The picture below has the path in the highlighted red box and I am curious if it because of the # before the fancy-box that makes this hidden. Any tips and language correction would be helpful as I am still learning how to scrape html. [image]

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(readr)

url <- read_html('https://www.draftkings.com/draft/contest/84207356')

rot <- url %>%
  html_nodes('..prize-payouts td+ td') %>%
  html_text()

roster <- data.frame(ROT = rot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website is using javascript to render the page.  One solution is to download the data as JSON.  If you examine the files from the network under the developer tools on your web browser.

This file should provide the information you are looking for:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON("https://api.draftkings.com/contests/v1/contests/84207356?format=json")
```

Be sure to comply with the term of service on this website.

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: I found it. Man I have looked through all api's they have and somehow overlooked that one. I will use that. Thanks!

Comment: What is the best library to use for get the Json to a data frame? I have been trying a lot of different things but not turning out. I am use the requests in python

Comment: @Mike.J, I find working with jsonlite package easy to use and it does what I want without requiring and additional dependences.  There are a few other packages out there.  If you are having troubles, post a new question with the JSON file in question and someone will help.